# how I setup view matrix?

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, directx

how I setup view matrix so that it works similer to 3ds max. in max if there a object which points to the left and you run over it, it will points to the left, even if you are looking at it from the other side. I want this for my 3d editor. thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks, I wil try it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract upward & side vectors from your camera and use them to align an object to a camera's view plane. This way your object will always be faced to the camera.